# Specs2 / SBT / Play -> How to output example names in JUnitXML files?

Tags: jenkins, junit, playframework, sbt, specs2

Here is what I have in my JUnit XML files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite hostname="sebastien-xps" name="service.AclServiceTest" tests="15" errors="0" failures="0" time="5.534">
   <properties>
      <property name="jline.esc.timeout" value="0" />
      <property name="config.resource" value="application-dev.conf" />
      <property name="java.runtime.name" value="Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment" />
      <property name="scala.concurrent.context.maxThreads" value="20" />
      <property name="sun.boot.library.path" value="/home/sebastien/Desktop/devhome/install/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64" />
      <property name="java.vm.version" value="24.45-b08" />
      <property name="java.vm.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation" />
      <property name="java.vendor.url" value="http://java.oracle.com/" />
      <property name="path.separator" value=":" />
      <property name="java.vm.name" value="Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM" />
      <property name="file.encoding.pkg" value="sun.io" />
      <property name="user.country" value="FR" />
      <property name="sun.java.launcher" value="SUN_STANDARD" />
      <property name="sun.os.patch.level" value="unknown" />
      <property name="java.vm.specification.name" value="Java Virtual Machine Specification" />
      <property name="user.dir" value="/home/sebastien/Desktop/Stample" />
      <property name="java.runtime.version" value="1.7.0_45-b18" />
      <property name="java.awt.graphicsenv" value="sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment" />
      <property name="java.endorsed.dirs" value="/home/sebastien/Desktop/devhome/install/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/endorsed" />
      <property name="os.arch" value="amd64" />
      <property name="java.io.tmpdir" value="/tmp" />
      <property name="line.separator" value=" " />
      <property name="java.vm.specification.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation" />
      <property name="os.name" value="Linux" />
      <property name="sun.jnu.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
      <property name="java.library.path" value="/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib" />
      <property name="sun.nio.ch.bugLevel" value="" />
      <property name="java.specification.name" value="Java Platform API Specification" />
      <property name="java.class.version" value="51.0" />
      <property name="sun.management.compiler" value="HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers" />
      <property name="os.version" value="3.5.0-54-generic" />
      <property name="user.home" value="/home/sebastien" />
      <property name="user.timezone" value="Europe/Paris" />
      <property name="java.awt.printerjob" value="sun.print.PSPrinterJob" />
      <property name="file.encoding" value="UTF8" />
      <property name="java.specification.version" value="1.7" />
      <property name="java.class.path" value="./sbt-launch-0.13.1.jar" />
      <property name="user.name" value="sebastien" />
      <property name="jline.shutdownhook" value="false" />
      <property name="scala.concurrent.context.minThreads" value="10" />
      <property name="java.vm.specification.version" value="1.7" />
      <property name="sun.java.command" value="./sbt-launch-0.13.1.jar" />
      <property name="java.home" value="/home/sebastien/Desktop/devhome/install/jdk1.7.0_45/jre" />
      <property name="sun.arch.data.model" value="64" />
      <property name="user.language" value="fr" />
      <property name="java.specification.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation" />
      <property name="stampleEnv" value="dev" />
      <property name="awt.toolkit" value="sun.awt.X11.XToolkit" />
      <property name="java.vm.info" value="mixed mode" />
      <property name="java.version" value="1.7.0_45" />
      <property name="java.ext.dirs" value="/home/sebastien/Desktop/devhome/install/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext" />
      <property name="sun.boot.class.path" value="/home/sebastien/Desktop/devhome/install/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/resources.jar:/home/sebastien/Desktop/devhome/install/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/sebastien/Desktop/devhome/install/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/home/sebastien/Desktop/devhome/install/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/home/sebastien/Desktop/devhome/install/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/jce.jar:/home/sebastien/Desktop/devhome/install/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/home/sebastien/Desktop/devhome/install/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/home/sebastien/Desktop/devhome/install/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/classes" />
      <property name="java.awt.headless" value="true" />
      <property name="java.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation" />
      <property name="file.separator" value="/" />
      <property name="java.vendor.url.bug" value="http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/" />
      <property name="sun.io.unicode.encoding" value="UnicodeLittle" />
      <property name="sun.cpu.endian" value="little" />
      <property name="sun.desktop" value="gnome" />
      <property name="sun.cpu.isalist" value="" />
   </properties>
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <system-out />
   <system-err />
</testsuite>
```

The interesting part is:

```
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
   <testcase classname="service.AclServiceTest" name="service.AclServiceTest" time="0.0" />
```

As you can see the example names are not included and this makes all examples impossible to identify on our Jenkins server. Can this be solved?

Note that it happens not for the `test` task but only for the `it:test` task that runs the integration tests.

Normal tests seems to be fine:

```
</testcase><testcase name="The username should::be valid when only lowercase chars and numbers" classname="utils.SignupUtilsTest" time="0,004">

</testcase><testcase name="The username should::be invalid when having too much characters" classname="utils.SignupUtilsTest" time="0,001">
```

I tried to use the same settings that Play use `in Test`:

```
  parallelExecution in IntegrationTest := false,
  testOptions in IntegrationTest += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.Specs2, "sequential", "true", "junitxml", "console"),
  testOptions in IntegrationTest += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "--ignore-runners=org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner"),
```

This does not seem to be any better.

Another strange thing is that the `it:test` files are not prefixed by their package name, unlike `test` files:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 sebastien sebastien  4096 mai    4 11:19 ./
drwxrwxr-x 8 sebastien sebastien  4096 mai    4 11:19 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastien sebastien  6152 mai    7 14:02 AclServiceTest.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastien sebastien  4864 mai    7 13:56 AnnotationUtilsTest.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastien sebastien  5013 mai    7 14:02 BreadcrumbServiceTest.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastien sebastien 11901 mai    7 14:01 CategoryServiceTest.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastien sebastien  4872 mai    7 14:02 CommentServiceTest.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastien sebastien  4652 mai    7 14:01 RelationshipServiceTest.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastien sebastien  4878 mai    7 14:02 ReminderServiceTest.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastien sebastien  4634 mai    7 14:02 SearchServiceTest.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastien sebastien 10660 mai    7 14:02 SharingServiceTest.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastien sebastien  5157 mai    7 13:56 SignupUtilsTest.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastien sebastien  7891 mai    7 14:01 StampleServiceTest.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastien sebastien 19606 mai    7 13:56 utils.AnnotationUtilsTest.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sebastien sebastien 20001 mai    7 13:56 utils.SignupUtilsTest.xml
```

Comment: Can you try to remove `TestFrameworks.JUnit` from the list of frameworks. I am not sure that the file you're seeing has been produced by specs2.